# Google chrome closes automatically after launching using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am on Windows 10 using Selenium with Python 3.7.3.

If I wrap the code inside a class , the browser terminates immediately after opening the page:

```
'''
Program to show how to open chrome browser using selenium webdriver
'''

from selenium import webdriver
#import os

class run_chrome_tests(object):

    def test_method(self):

        # This is the location of the chrome driver saved into a variable
        #driver_location = "D:\\Udemy_Python\\Libs\\chromedriver.exe"

        # Letting the system environment know the location of the chrome driver
        #os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location

        # Letting the chrome browser know the location of the chrome driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com")


ch = run_chrome_tests()
ch.test_method()
```

Comment: Works fine and doesn't terminate when I run your code on my machine. Is there an error?

Comment: Can you perform an action after opening the webpage, like driver.find_element....click()

Answer (score 2):

Check the Version of the Chrome Browser and the Version of the chrome Driver , if the driver is not compatible then browser terminates just after opening,try using the latest version for both

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, the chrome window will shutdown automatically, after it finishes all the instruments, unless you set the option to prevent this explicitly.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
   driver.get("http://www.bing.com")
   ```
2. However, there is another possibility that you had chosen a **WRONG** version of chrome driver. The following is on how to select the right version of the chrome driver:

   In the address bar of your chrome browser, type chrome://version. The first line of the returned page will be the version number.

   Download one version of the chrome driver from this page. (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Select the version that matches the version of your chrome as much as possible. (Very Important)